# In spite of the ref being tagged on variables in python, the datatype doesn't change on reassigning?

Tags: python, list, copy

In the below python code, i am creating a list1 and then assigning the value of that to list2. And when i append a value to list2 the value gets reflected in list1. This is because the ref of list1 is tagged to list2.

Wouldn't this inturn mean that any change that i make to the variable list2 should inturn reflect on the variable list1 as well? I am a bit confused here. I did go around searching everywhere but there hasn't been this question answered yet.

All i did is change the datatype of list2 again by reassigning it to a string. But then to by disbelief the datatype of list1 is a list with the same old value.

```
>>> list1 = [1, 2, 3]
>>> list2 = list1
>>> list2.append(4)
>>> print(list1)
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> print(list2)
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> # now since list 2 is also tagged to the same ref as list 1, when i change the value of list2
... # list1 should also ideally change. Isn't it?
...
>>> list2 = "Making the list as a string"
>>> print(list2)
Making the list as a string
>>> print(list1)
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> # why does this happen??
...
```

**Extension of the question based on the solution provided:**

Since python variables are defined dynamically based on what values are assigned. The values would have a ref address tagged to it. So the list would indeed reflect in both the variables if even one is appended. But now if that is the case, the below code should have changed the value of the list1 variable (i know its a bit silly of me to ask, but it killing me to know why not?!).

```
>>> id([1, 2])
49713680
>>> list1 = [1, 2]
>>> id(list1)
49713680
>>> # Here both the variable and raw list value has the same memory location
... # Now in case i use append on the raw data list, shouldn't it reflect 
... # on the variable tagged to it as well (since they both point to the     
... # same address)?
>>> [1, 2].append(3)
>>> print(list1)
[1, 2]
... # shouldn't this change to [1, 2, 3] since they refer the same address?
>>> id([1, 2])
49713760
>>> id(list1)
49713680
```

Also i was able to see that the id of the raw list([1, 2]) has now changed from what it was previously.

Comment: Try doing id([1,2]) after list1 = [1,2] and you'll see it has changed, so your append is actually referring to a different thing now. Also looks like temporary items are always getting the same id, for example this is true: id([1,2]) == id([1,2,3]) == id([1,2,3,4])

Comment: If you want to ask "why" too deeply from here I think we'll have to start reading the cpython source code :)

Comment: Yeah kinda makes sense. Thanks a lot though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"list1" and "list2" are names that can point to different Python objects. You can create objects in memory, and then use names to point to them. If you are curious, you can use the **id** function to see the memory address a name points to.

Build a list with 1, 2, 3 in it, then make the name "list1" point to it.

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3]
```

Make name "list2" point to where name "list1" is pointing to. Now both names "list1" and "list2" point to the same thing, but they are still different names.

```
list2 = list1
# id(list1) == id(list2)
```

Call the append method of what the name "list2" is pointing to.

```
list2.append(4)
```

Change the name "list2" to point to a string constant. Now name "list1" still refers to the list object as before, but "list2" has been changed to refer to a string.

```
list2 = "Making the list as a string"
# Now id(list1) != id(list2)
```

Show the contents of what "list1" and "list2" names point to.

```
print(list2)
print(list1)
```

*(If you want to go into more detail, you could even explicitly see the name references changing by disassembling your python program with "python -m dis your_program.py")*

Comment: So by what you are trying to say, if any raw data be it string, list, integer, if entered into python prompt directly (>>>[1, 2, 3] ) would inturn gets saved into a memory location and it would persist there. And incase we are not tagging that to a variable, technically we wont be able to modify / alter that list or number in that memory location. Correct? If this is the case, this would kinda answer my question.

Comment: Kind of, except Python also counts from how many places an object is pointed to, and may remove it from memory if unused. You can look at this refcount if you are interested, import sys; sys.getrefcount(some_object)

Comment: Yup i tried that, it makes sense. Thank you. Though i have one last doubt, i know its really silly but please bear with me. I have updated my above question with that.